# Comparing two contact .scv files in excel (one from google contacts and the other from outlook)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-outlook, google-contacts

Ok so when i linked my google contacts with outlook contacts on my iPhone it created many duplicates in both applications (along with Icloud contacts but i cant export any of them in to .csv only vcard), its a pain trying to sort through all of them and insert the missing data, is there a way to use excel for comparing the two list? i am new at excel

Answer (score 0):

Excel can not read vCard files. You have to convert it to a .csv. Luckily, this is easy. In Windows 7 or newer, copy the vCard file to your Contacts folder (located at C:\Users\YOU\Contacts). Then, select the file and Choose "Export > CSV (Comma Separated Values)
[image]